# Specifying logback.xml in Java Maven project

Tags: java, maven, logback

I have a Java maven project where I need to use logback as the logging framework. I have placed the logback.xml configuration file in the src/main/conf folder. However, it looks like it is not getting picked up because src/main/conf is not in the class path. On building the project I copy all the contents of that folder to target/root/conf and wanted to have that directory as part of my classpath. Can anyone let me know how can I force that?

Comment: Just move it to `src/main/resources` folder.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In a Maven project the default directory for resource file is `src/main/resources`. This is the [layout directory](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html),
if you still want to change this default, follow these [instructions](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html).